# This CSS into a SASS list (with the class name being inserted into a property)?

Tags: css, list, sass

How would I convert this repetitive CSS into a SASS list so that the class (in reality there are 50+ classes, not just 3 like here, for all of the SVG icons) name automatically ends up in the background-img: url property?

```
.boy{
 background: url(../svg/boy.svg);
}

.car{
 background: url(../svg/car.svg);
}

.house{
 background: url(../svg/house.svg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$list: boy house car;
@each $item in $list {
    .#{$item}{ 
        background: url(../svg/#{$item}.svg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the variables as part of a SASS list and then iterate over them like this

```
$svg-list: "boy", "car", "house";

@each $i in $svg-list {
  .#{$i} {
    background: url(../svg/#{$i}.svg);
  }
}
```

See it in action [here](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/fc38262b48acbbb6ae8ee37bef788001).